# presto athena tables as variables

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I have an SQL in aws-athena which looks more or less like this

```
SELECT * FROM "db1"."2021_08_31" WHERE condition
Union
SELECT * FROM "db2"."2021_08_31" WHERE condition

...
```

Is there an intelligent way of rewriting this, so in case I want to switch from `2021_08_31` to `2021_09_30` I would only need to change it in one place. For example as follows (which does not work)

```
tbl = "2021_09_30"

SELECT * FROM "db1".tbl WHERE condition
Union
SELECT * FROM "db2".tbl WHERE condition
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a WITH clause to factor out the access to the underlying table:

```sql
WITH data AS (TABLE "db1"."2021_08_31")
SELECT * FROM data WHERE condition1
UNION
SELECT * FROM data WHERE condition2
...
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this will not work since there are two different dbs db1 and db2. The table name is the same in both and my goal is to right the table name only once.

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not support this feature. You can use the Athena API and the StartQueryExecution call and have a template for this query that you render before you submit the job.

Comment: Thanks that sounds interesting. Is something similar also available when using the Athena web ui?